# Imprimir ultimas cifras de un numero

Tags: c

¿Podéis ayudarme con una duda? Necesito hacer un programa en C que imprima las últimas dos cifras de un número, por ejemplo, el usuario introduce 3412, el programa debe imprimir 12.

He pensado en lo siguiente:

```
 while(num>99){
        num=num-100;
    }
```

Y esto funciona pero me gustaría saber si hay una forma mejor de hacerlo, algo como "2%d" o algo así.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Funciona para números menores a 200 y mayores a 99. Para 3412 no funciona :) Podrías probar el manipular lo que ingresa el usuario como una cadena, no como un número; ahí se hace trivial

Comment: Sí funciona lo que pasa es que lo veo muy a fuerza bruta. ¿A qué te refieres? Si lo recibo como cadena sigo teniendo el mismo problema, es decir, no se como actuar sobre ella

Comment: Miras la longitud del char array e imprimes los últimos dos caracteres valiéndote de que sabes la longitud. Aunque la solución propuesta, usando mod 100 también es muy práctica

Comment: De una cadena puedes obtener su longitud (*strlen*) y usar ese dato para sacar los dos últimos caracteres en un nuevo string (no te olvides del \0 final)

Answer (score 5):

tienes que calcular el módulo del número, esto es, el residuo de la división. Para ello debes usar el operador `%`:

```
1234 / 100 = 12
1234 % 100 = 34

12345678 / 100 = 123456
12345678 % 100 = 78
```

Es decir:

```
num = num % 100;
```

O, si prefieres la forma resumida:

```
num %= 100;
```

Comment: Cierto muchas gracias, no había caído en eso.